Should date be a random variable in a mixed model, or included as an interactive term with my categorical variable?
I'm concerned with the effect of herbicide on percent cover of weeds. I've included a small dataset below. Initially, I thought to use the mixed model:
mixed_model_1 <- lmer(Percent_Coverage ~ Herbicide * Date + (1|Location), data = data)

However, after some discussion, I am now not sure whether I should include Date as I did above, or use the model:
mixed_model_2 <- lmer(Percent_Coverage ~ Herbicide + (1|Location) + (1|Date), data = data)

I'm inclined to think model 1 is more appropriate for the repeated measures, but I'm not sure now. I'm not really that interested in the Date interaction--I would expect date to have an influence because the herbicide's effect will become more prominent with time (they take a while to show full effect). Full transparency (if you haven't figured it out already), I am no stat wiz.
EDIT: I'm MAINLY interested in whether a given herbicide ultimately can give some level of control to percent coverage, but less interested in how quickly it does it. So to say I'm not interested in the interaction was misleading, sorry.
EDIT: The full data set has 5 herbicides (including no treatment), 3 locations, and 5 dates
I'm using R.4.4.2
Here is the data and what I've run on it:
data <- structure(list(Location = c("Low Arm", "Low Arm", "Low Arm", 
                                    "Low Arm", "Low Arm", "Low Arm", "Low Arm", "Low Arm", "Low Arm", 
                                    "Masonic", "Masonic", "Masonic", "Masonic", "Masonic", "Masonic", 
                                    "Masonic", "Masonic", "Masonic", "Up Arm", "Up Arm", "Up Arm", 
                                    "Up Arm", "Up Arm", "Up Arm", "Up Arm", "Up Arm", "Up Arm"), 
                       Date = c("7/1/2024", "7/1/2024", "7/1/2024", "7/22/2024", 
                                   "7/22/2024", "7/22/2024", "8/5/2024", "8/5/2024", "8/5/2024", 
                                   "7/1/2024", "7/1/2024", "7/1/2024", "7/22/2024", "7/22/2024", 
                                   "7/22/2024", "8/5/2024", "8/5/2024", "8/5/2024", "7/1/2024", 
                                   "7/1/2024", "7/1/2024", "7/22/2024", "7/22/2024", "7/22/2024", 
                                   "8/5/2024", "8/5/2024", "8/5/2024"), 
                       Herbicide = c("Firehawk", "No Treatment", "Weed Master", "Firehawk", "No Treatment", 
                                     "Weed Master", "Firehawk", "No Treatment", "Weed Master", 
                                     "Firehawk", "No Treatment", "Weed Master", "Firehawk", "No Treatment", 
                                     "Weed Master", "Firehawk", "No Treatment", "Weed Master", 
                                     "Firehawk", "No Treatment", "Weed Master", "Firehawk", "No Treatment", 
                                     "Weed Master", "Firehawk", "No Treatment", "Weed Master"), 
                       Percent_Coverage = c(15L, 80L, 75L, 10L, 60L, 10L, 0L, 5L, 
                                            2L, 70L, 95L, 80L, 15L, 80L, 35L, 0L, 60L, 5L, 30L, 90L, 
                                            45L, 5L, 55L, 5L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                      "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -27L))


mixed_model_1 <- lmer(Percent_Coverage ~ Herbicide * Date + (1|Location), data = data)

anova(mixed_model_1)

Output:
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
Herbicide       8436.5  4218.3     2    16 24.8729 1.230e-05 ***
Date           14477.0  7238.5     2    16 42.6816 3.854e-07 ***
Herbicide:Date  1574.1   393.5     4    16  2.3205    0.1013    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

mixed_model_2 <-  lmer(Percent_Coverage ~ Herbicide + (1|Location) + (1|Date), data = data)

anova(mixed_model_2)

Output:
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
          Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
Herbicide 8436.5  4218.3     2    20  19.676 1.887e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```


Is date a measure of time as in a longitudinal model or just an identifier of clustering of observations (I.e. those occurring on date X)? From your data it looks like the latter but your description (the effect of time) suggests the former. That will be the main determinant of how to specify your model

wezlc raises a valid point and the answer to his question will guide how you specify the model.  That being said, if you only have a few dates, I'd recommend scaling dates to a timepoint that makes sense for your study, convert dates to a continuous numeric variable (e.g. t=0, 1, 2, ) and include them as fixed effects if the date is a measure of time.  Date random effects are not great for capturing time trends (e.g. seasonality).  If the dates are not of primary interest, and you want to account for heterogeneity by date, I'd include them as random effects.

I would expect date to have an influence because the herbicide's effect will become more prominent with time (they take a while to show full effect). This makes me think you should re-code the Date variable into a time_since_treatment variable and include as an appropriate predictor

@RickHass the former. There are a couple other dates in the full data set that I omitted here

@wezlc I would argue that you should pick an index date and have a measure of time as another comment suggested, however, Dr. Bolker knows his stuff, so his recommendations are also good. If you do want to model the change in percent coverage over time, then you'll have to include a time fixed effect variable based on date.

Let's compare several possible specifications. I'm going to assume/suggest that you set options(contrasts = c("contr.sum", "contr.poly")) first if you want to test main effects in the presence of an interaction ...

Herbicide * Date: this considers the effect of herbicide (averaging across date), the effects of different dates (averaging across herbicides), and their interaction.

If the data you showed us above are representative (i.e., you only have data from a few different sampling dates, in a balanced layout) this is probably what you should use; unless you are using classical ANOVA (e.g. aov() with appropriate Error terms), mixed models will work poorly when there are only three levels of the grouping variable (Herbicide).
Alternatives:

Herbicide + (1|Date): this considers the effect of herbicide (again effectively averaging across date), and random variation in the percent coverage across dates, but does not consider the interaction.

Herbicide + (1|Date/Herbicide): this considers variation among herbicides as a fixed effect and variation among dates, and among herbicides within dates, as random effects.

Herbicide + (Herbicide | Date): this also considers the interaction, but allows for different correlations among different pairs of herbicides (almost certainly overkill/not feasible with this data set).


And, because you should always plot your data:
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
data$Herbicide <- reorder(factor(data$Herbicide), -data$Percent_Coverage)
ggplot(data, aes(Herbicide, Percent_Coverage, 
   colour = Date, shape = Location)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   geom_line(aes(group = interaction(Date, Location)), 
      linewidth =4, alpha = 0.2)


Diagnostics (performance::check_model()) look adequate too.

And if they have a decently large number of dates, they should convert to time since start of experiment and just fit a smoother (probably with interaction) for that. I'm also concerned about OP's statement "I'm not really that interested in the Date interaction". The interaction of treatment with the time effect should be of utmost interest in this research.

@Ben sorry, I've edited the question--the full data set has five levels of the grouping variable (Herbicide), not three. In that case, would you then still include location as a random effect?
